# onCreate() is not running when i switch to the activity or onDataChanged is getting called first

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i am working on a school project and i am using firebase authentication with email and password. i have a problem when a user sing in, then returns to the sing in page and tries to create a new account. when clicking the submit button to create his new account instead of going back to the sign in page, it goes to the users main page. this only happens if a user has already singed in and then tries to sign up another account. i have tried signin out the user when he is returning to the sign in page but it didnt work. here is my code:

sign in page:

```
public class SignIn extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText email,pass;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseUser user;
FirebaseDatabase db;
DatabaseReference mRef;
String type,name;

public ProgressDialog pd;

Context context;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    email = findViewById(R.id.inpSigninEmail);
    pass = findViewById(R.id.inpSigninPass);
    db.getInstance();
    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users/");
    type=null;
    name=null;
    context=this;
    Log.e("asd","Loginoncreate");
}

public void signIn (View view){
    if (email.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1 || pass.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill your information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Signing in...");
        pd.show();
        mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString(), pass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    mRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                            while (type==null){
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                                    type = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("/Type").getValue());
                                    if (type!="null"){
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            while (name==null){
                                for (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot : snapshot.getChildren()){
                                    name = String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUid()).child("/Name").getValue());
                                    if (name!="null"){
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            pd.dismiss();
                            if (type.matches("user")){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, UserMain.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                type=null;
                                name=null;
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                                Log.e("as","loginUser");
                            }else{
                                Intent intent = new Intent(context, CompanyMain.class);
                                intent.putExtra("name", name);
                                startActivity(intent);
                                finish();
                                type=null;
                                name=null;
                            }
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {
                            pd.dismiss();
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    pd.dismiss();
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

public void signUp (View view){
    startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this, SignUp.class));
    finish();
}
```

}

sign up page:

```
public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText name,email,pass;
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
FirebaseDatabase db;
FirebaseUser user;
RadioButton Rbtn;
RadioGroup Rgroup;
DatabaseReference mRef;

boolean out = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    name = findViewById(R.id.inpSignupName);
    email = findViewById(R.id.inpSignupEmail);
    pass = findViewById(R.id.inpSignupPass);
    Rgroup = findViewById(R.id.radioGroup);
    db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
    mRef = db.getReference("Users/");
    Log.e("asd","Signuponcreate");
}

public void submit (View view){
    if (name.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1 || email.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1 || pass.getText().toString().trim().length() < 1){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please fill your information.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }else{
        mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email.getText().toString() , pass.getText().toString()).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Sign Up success!",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    user = mAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    int radioId = Rgroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
                    Rbtn = findViewById(radioId);
                    if (Rbtn.getText().equals("User")){
                        mRef.child("/Normal").child(user.getUid()).child("/Name").setValue(name.getText().toString());
                        mRef.child("/Normal").child(user.getUid()).child("/Type").setValue("user");
                    }else{
                        mRef.child("/Company").child(user.getUid()).child("/Name").setValue(name.getText().toString());
                        mRef.child("/Company").child(user.getUid()).child("/Type").setValue("company");
                    }
                    startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, SignIn.class));
                    finish();
                    Log.e("as","signupUserGotoSignin");
                }else{
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), task.getException().getMessage(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

}

and here are my logs:

E/asd: Loginoncreate  (this is the first message i see and its when i start up the app,then i sign in and go to user main page)

E/as: loginUser   (when i sign in the first time while the is opened and go to users main page)

E/asd: Loginoncreate  (When i return from the users main page)

E/asd: Signuponcreate   (i go to create a new account)

E/as: signupUserGotoSignin   (i create the account and want to return to the sign in page)

E/as: loginUser  (here i would expect the Loginoncreate message again but i never get it, i always get this message 2 times. this message is onDataChanged)
E/as: loginUser

after i click the submit button to create the new account it never returns to the sign in page. i know that firebase is asynchronous but i dont know what i am doing wrong here. why the onCreate on sign in page never gets called and it goes immediately in the onDataChanged and takes me to the users main page?

Answer (score 0):

I assume that signIn (View view) method is your signIn button click event. So,

**firstly,** you need to remove **onClick** attribute from button XML code.

```
android:onClick="signIn"
```

then, create onClick button event in onCreate() method.

**Like,**

```
Button button = findViewById(R.id.SignInbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            //put your signIn button all code here
        }
    });
```

The same thing does in the SignUp page activity.

Comment: thanks for answering, i tried it like this just now and i still get the same result. i havent been able to figure out what exactly happens or why its happening. let me know if i need to provide any more information. i am still really confused on why this happens since the submit button take the user to the sign in page, the onCreate method never gets called and i dont know why. Also is there any difference between using buttons the way i did and the way you showed in your answer? do they function in a different way?

Comment: Can you post your XML  of sign-in and Signup?

Answer (score 0):

Okay so i put everything i have inside the onDataChange under an If statement where i check temp variable if its true, and right before i am move the user to the users main page i make that variable false. this fixed my problem but if someone have an explanation on why this was happening before i would still appreciate it. thanks